# Can't Find the Split selected features with selected line from another layer tool

Tags: qgis, polygon, line, splitting, digitizing

I'm trying to split a selected polygon features with a selected line from another feature layer.

I, however, can't seem to get the tool for this to show up in my advanced digitize toolbar.

In other words, I need someone to tell me how to get my advanced digitizing toolbar to look like this:
 [image]
  My current toolbar only contains the first half of these tools.
I need to gain access to the [image]
  "Split selected feature with select line from another layer" tool and have it  show up at the top of my screen.

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: @PolyGeo - I'm almost certain it's QGIS.

Answer (score 4):

You didn't specify it in your question but it looks like you are using QGIS.

The *"Split selected feature with select line from another layer"* tool is from the **Digitizing Tools** plugin. You may need to download/install from the toolbar menu:

*Plugins > Manage and Install Plugins*

Once installed and enabled, it should show up in the toolbar. If not then right-click anywhere on the toolbar and you should see the option to enable it:

[image: Toolbar options]

The icon for the *"Split selected feature with select line from another layer"* tool is this one:

[image: Split selected tool]

Answer (score 1):

The **Split selected features with selected line from another layer** has been removed since the 1.4.0 Version of the digitizing tools plugin ([github page of the plugin](https://github.com/bstroebl/DigitizingTools/wiki/Usage))

They suggest to use the processing's in-place editing **Split with lines** instead.