# QGIS 3.4 Split Features

Tags: qgis

I have just started using QGIS 3.4 and want to split a polygon with a line from another layer. I can do this in 2.18 but there is no option in 3.4

Is this correct, is the tool not available

[image]

Comment: Did you see this thread?  https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/339113/split-polygon-with-selected-line-from-another-layer-in-qgis?rq=1

Comment: Just saw the thread and the process works,