# QGIS, lines that spans around the world

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I have a dataset in a PostgreSQL database with lines for the global ship traffic that I want to visualize in QGIS, when I use "WGS 84 / Pseudo-Mercator" projection (3857) the lines connecting e.g. US and Kina spans over Europe and if I change the projection to something like the "WGS 84 / PDC Mercator" (3832) the lines connecting Europe and US goes the "wrong" way.

Is there any setting etc. in QGIS that could terminate lines at the right/left side of the screen instead?

[image: QGIS global ship traffic]

Comment: You will need to cut your traversing lines at the international date line, making the leading lines' X = 180 and the trailing lines' X = -180 geographically to span the Pacific Ocean to have it display properly on this map.

Comment: See here: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/398090/88814