# Defining a custom central meridian and latitude of orgin for Winkel I projection in QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system

I'm trying to redefine the Winkel I projection using the Custom Projection option in QGIS to define the central meridian as -100 (100 degrees west) and the latitude of origin as 40 degrees north.  I'm assuming if I got the parameters right it would centre my world map on the USA?

I've tried copying the existing Winkel I parameters and adjusting +long_0 to -100 and +lat_ts to 40 but I keep getting a "not valid" message?  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try to validate it before using it ?

Comment: Posting your WKT or Proj String code would help.

Comment: Also, read carefully the not-valid message. All custom projections are being evaluated and some times the message is not about the custom projection you are currently defining but another already defined one.

Answer (score 3):

With the following WKT definition, I get a valid Winkel 1 projection centered at x=-100, y=40 degrees:

```
PROJCRS["unknown",
    BASEGEOGCRS["unknown",
        DATUM["World Geodetic System 1984",
            ELLIPSOID["WGS 84",6378137,298.257223563,
                LENGTHUNIT["metre",1]],
            ID["EPSG",6326]],
        PRIMEM["Greenwich",0,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8901]]],
    CONVERSION["unknown",
        METHOD["Winkel I"],
        PARAMETER["Longitude of natural origin",-100,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8802]],
        PARAMETER["Latitude of 1st standard parallel",40,
            ANGLEUNIT["degree",0.0174532925199433],
            ID["EPSG",8823]],
        PARAMETER["False easting",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8806]],
        PARAMETER["False northing",0,
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1],
            ID["EPSG",8807]]],
    CS[Cartesian,2],
        AXIS["(E)",east,
            ORDER[1],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]],
        AXIS["(N)",north,
            ORDER[2],
            LENGTHUNIT["metre",1,
                ID["EPSG",9001]]]]
```

*Result - for the streched shapes, see here [QGIS Vector layer stretched across entire map](https://gis.stackexchange.com/q/396460/88814:)*
[image]